# Как написать программу, которая будет заканчиваться используя "q"? И, чтобы если юзер вводил какой-то символ, который приведет к ошибке

Tags: c

Что ж, мне нужно cложить мои целые числа, но также мне нужно сделать выход из программы, если пользователь вводит «q», но если он / она вводит любой другой символ, это приведет к ошибке. Однако моя программа не видит цикл while, и я не знаю почему, потому что мне это кажется логичным ... Если вы можете мне помочь, это будет действительно здорово. Спасибо заранее. (если я использую `while (entered) {..,` будет бесконечно «Error. Try again». Возможно, вопрос глупый, может я туплю, но буду очень благодарна, если мне сможете помочь и привести пример кода.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    int first_number;
    int second_number;
    int concatenation;
    char any_symbol;
    bool entered = true;
    printf("Enter the first number. ");
    scanf("%d",&first_number);
    printf("Enter the second number. ");
    scanf("%d", &second_number);
    printf("Enter any symbol (this will lead you to the error). But if you choose 'q', the program will exit. \n");
    scanf("%s", &any_symbol);
    printf("The symbol is: %c\n", any_symbol);
    concatenation = first_number + second_number;
    printf("The concatenation is: %d\n", concatenation);
    while (!entered) {
        if (strcmp (&any_symbol, "q") == 0) {
            break;
        }
        else if (any_symbol) {
            printf("Error. Try again.");
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Enter the first number. 1
Enter the second number. 2
Enter any symbol (this will lead you to the error). But if you choose 'q', the program will exit. 
w
The symbol is: w
The concatenation is: 3
```

Или:

```
Enter the first number. 1
Enter the second number. 2
Enter any symbol (this will lead you to the error). But if you choose 'q', the program will exit. 
q
The symbol is: q
The concatenation is: 3
```

Comment: Не помню уже всех подводных камней `c`, но что-то мне кажется, что у вас перенос строки попал вместе с `q`, т.е. `"q\n"`. Можете проверить, что возращает `stdlen`?

Comment: не в этом дело.

Comment: Все, понял
У вас `any_symbol` это `char`. Сделайте `char any_symbol[3]`, чтобы это было строкой :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Честно говоря, я не понимаю Вашей задумки и что мешает сделать правильно. Я заменил ввод символа `any_symbol` - `scanf(" %c", &any_symbol);` (пробел перед %c должен выкинуть все пробельные символы (в том числе и символ перевода строки), что остались от предыдущего ввода), заголовок цикла `while (entered)` и проверку условия `if (any_symbol == 'q')`. При этом, совершенно не понятно, что должно произойти в случае неверного ввода. Нужно потребовать новый ввод данных? - тогда цикл Вы начали немного поздновато. Пока я просто определяю неверный ввод и останавливаю цикл.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    int first_number;
    int second_number;
    int concatenation;
    char any_symbol;
    bool entered = true;
    printf("Enter the first number. ");
    scanf("%d", &first_number);
    printf("Enter the second number. ");
    scanf("%d", &second_number);
    printf("Enter any symbol (this will lead you to the error). But if you choose 'q', the program will exit. \n");
//    scanf("%s", &any_symbol);
    scanf(" %c", &any_symbol);
    printf("The symbol is: %c\n", any_symbol);
    concatenation = first_number + second_number;
    printf("The concatenation is: %d\n", concatenation);
    while (entered) {
//        if (strcmp(any_symbol, "q") == 0) {
        if (any_symbol == 'q') {
            break;
        }
        else if (any_symbol) {
            printf("Error. Try again.\n");
            entered = false;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @WhiteBlinder, Вы можете принять правильный ответ ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ваша программа заработает в таком виде. Обратите внимание на тип `any_symbol`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    int first_number;
    int second_number;
    int concatenation;
    char any_symbol[3];
    bool entered = false;
    printf("Enter the first number. ");
    scanf("%d", &first_number);
    printf("Enter the second number. ");
    scanf("%d", &second_number);
    printf("Enter any symbol (this will lead you to the error). But if you choose 'q', the program will exit. \n");
    scanf("%s", &any_symbol);
    printf("The symbol is: %s\n", any_symbol);
    concatenation = first_number + second_number;
    printf("The concatenation is: %d\n", concatenation);
    entered = true;    

    while (!entered) {
        if (strcmp(any_symbol, "q") == 0) {
            break;
        }
        else if (any_symbol) {
            printf("Error. Try again.");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: по-прежнему, нет( в любом случае, спасибо за вашу старательность

Comment: @WhiteBlinder, посмотрите на свой заголовок цикла `while (!entered)` внимательно и на инициализацию переменной `entered`. И больше нигде эта переменная не меняется. Очевидно же, что этот цикл и не должен был выполняться.

Comment: это логично, что он не изменится. вопрос в том, КАК ЗАСТАВИТЬ ЕГО ВЫПОЛНЯТЬСЯ, не переписывая мой код полностью. Если я бы использовала бы while(entered), у меня была бы бесконечная ошибка, что написано в вопросе. Если хотите помочь - напишите тот блок кода правильно.

Comment: Это нелогично для этой программы

Comment: спасибо огромное!